# Establish bounds for type members within a type alias in Scala

Tags: scala, type-members

Given:

```
trait Record {
  type ID
  val id: ID
}

trait DataSource {
  type ID
  def read(id: ID): Try[R]
}
```

I'd like to be able to describe the `read` function generically.

```
type Reader[R <: Record, DS <: DataSource] = (DS#ID) => Try[R]
```

How can I guarantee type safety here such that `DS#ID` won't be a dissimilar type as `R#ID`?
I tried...

```
type Reader[R <: Record, DS <: DataSource, R#ID <: DS#ID] = (DS#ID) => Try[R]
```

But that doens't compile.  What is the correct syntax for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with the type parameters of `Reader`, `ID` has to be pulled out as it's own parameter.

```
type Reader[R <: Record, DS <: DataSource, ID] = (ID) => Try[R]
```

Once this is done it's possible to then place additional bounds onto it...

```
type Reader[R <: Record, DS <: DataSource, ID <: DS#ID =:= R#ID] = (ID) => Try[R]
```